# how to put cursor focus on textbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, focus

I have a WPF usercontrol which contains controls and I want to put focus on a textbox I tried to use "FocusManager.FocusedElement" but i can't type in bacause tab is set to the first control in the usercontrol.

[image]

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="160"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="272*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnCreationOffre" Background="Transparent" Width ="120" Height="35" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Click="btnCreationOffre_Click" Margin="0,2,0,8" Style="{DynamicResource nv_offreButton}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnModifierOffre" Background="Transparent" Width ="120" Height="35" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnModifierOffre_Click" Margin="130,2,0,8" Style="{DynamicResource modifierButton}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnConsulterOffre" Width ="120" Height="35" Content="Consulter" HorizontalAlignment="left" Click="btnConsulterOffre_Click" Margin="260,2,0,8" Style="{DynamicResource consulterButton}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSuppOffre" Background="Transparent" Width ="120" Height="35" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnSuppOffre_Click" Margin="390,2,0,8" Style="{DynamicResource suppButton}" />
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Gray" Height="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />

        <Grid x:Name="gridFocus" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">Numéro offre</TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxNumOffre" Height="30" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

What I want is when i open this usercontrol i can type in the textboxshown above named "textBoxNumOffre"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your method (in your xaml.cs) that gets called when the usercontrol gets loaded:

```
public YourUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {
        Keyboard.Focus(textBoxNumOffre);
    }, DispatcherPriority.Render);
}
```